# Magento :1.7 - Same products have different prices based on magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Scenario -

I have a single domain and four sub-domains . I want to sell same products on all sub-domains but with different price for same product. Is it possible in magento ?

If Yes, Kindly provide the solution .

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. The **Price** attribute is website-scoped attribute. So you should create 4 websites (for each subdomain), and you'll have one set of products for each of the Websites, and possibility to assign different prices for each website.

To turn this feature on, open your admin panel, go to *System/Configuration/Catalog*, open *Price* tab and set **Catalog Price Scope** to Website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. The Price attribute set for same product for every website . So you should create 4 websites (for each subdomain), and you'll have one set of products for each of the Websites, and possibility to assign different prices for each website.

Step 1.  In the Admin panel, goto System, Configuration, Catalog, then Price.

Step 2. Change Price from Global to Website.

Step 3. You should see “Website” on the price page for the product now, instead of “Global”.

Step 4. For each product you want to set different prices on – select the product, then in the upper left corner you will see the option to chose your store view.  Select the first store

Step 5. Set the price for the first store and click “Save and Continue Editing”

Step 6. Select the store view for your second store and set the price for that store

Step 7. Repeat step 6 until all of your store have the prices you want.